# How to use @Conditional, and what Conditional contains?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm learning about autoconfigurations in Spring Boot. I don't know what is Spring Context, what Spring Context contains, what is `Conditional`?

What is different between `@ConditionalOnClass`, `@Conditional`, `@ConditionalOnBean` and others?
So anyone can help me. And I'm so happy if we have any example

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of these classes?

Comment: And in general it may be hard to understand how Spring works if you don't know what is Spring Context. You may wish to consult Spring documentation first: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: And for Spring Boot conditionals http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-understanding-auto-configured-beans